# Pydev пишет SyntaxError на params из библиотеки requests. Как пофиксить?

Tags: python, requests, xubuntu, pydev

> Вот заготовка кода

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

names=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s , t, u, v, w, x]

c=0

while c<24:

    response = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/' params={'b':requests+n:names[c]})
    if response.status_code==200:

        print('Success!')

    elif 
        response.status_code==404:

        print('Not Found.')
```

> Console:

```
response=requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/' param**s**={'q':requests+n:names[c]})


SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: не пробовали data вместо params использовать?

Comment: поставьте запятую после url

Answer (score 2):

У вас не хватает запятой после `'https://www.instagram.com/'`